# Convert dataframe date row to a weekend / not weekend value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a DATE row and I need to convert it to a row of value 1 if the date is a weekend day and 0 if it is not.

So far, I converted the data to weekdays

```
df['WEEKDAY'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.dayofweek
```

It's there a way to create this "WEEKEND" row without functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why without functions?

Comment: `df["WEEKDAY"] = df["WEEKDAY"] < 5`  (I think at least , this assumes saturday is 5 and sunday is 6)

Comment: Thanks, @JoranBeasley but it gives TRUE or FALSE and not O and 1.

Comment: But adding .astype(float) as @dagrha's solution it works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's the solution I've come up with:

```
df['WEEKDAY'] = ((pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).dayofweek) // 5 == 1).astype(float)
```

Essentially all it does is use integer division (`//`) to test whether the `dayofweek` attribute of the `DatetimeIndex` is less than 5.  Normally this would return just a `True` or `False`, but tacking on the `astype(float)` at the end returns a 1 or 0 rather than a boolean.

Comment: Very smart, thanks! So I have now two solutions, as df["WEEKDAY"] = (df["WEEKDAY"] < 5).astype(float) also works like a charm!

Comment: This will work fine although using an inequality as in Joran's comment is much more readable.

Comment: This answer appears to be slightly off. The weekdays have values [0,1,2,3,4] and weekends [5,6]. Let's consider the dayofweek 4 : 4//5 != 1 therefore we get a 0. In other words, the answer needs to replace the label 'WEEKDAY' with 'WEEKEND' or the 1 in the predicate needs to be replaced with a 0.

Comment: you could do this as well df['weekend'] = df['datetime'].dt.dayofweek>=5 ... my dateime is a column not an index but the idea remains the same

Answer (score 5):

One more way of getting weekend indicator is by `where` function:

```
df['WEEKDAY'] = np.where((df['DATE']).dt.dayofweek) < 5,0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way of getting weekend indicator is by first converting the date column to day of the week and then using those values to get weekend/not weekend. This can be implemented as follows:

```
df['WEEKDAY'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.dayofweek  # monday = 0, sunday = 6

df['weekend_indi'] = 0          # Initialize the column with default value of 0
df.loc[df['WEEKDAY'].isin([5, 6]), 'weekend_indi'] = 1  # 5 and 6 correspond to Sat and Sun
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the top voted answer in some codebase. Please don't do it that way, it's completely unreadable. Instead do:

```py
df['weekend'] = df['date'].dt.day_name().isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday'])
```

Note: `df['date']` needs to be in `datetime64` or similar format.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I found is:

```
df['WEEKEND'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekday > 4
```

The question asks for 0 or 1 instead of True and False, just multiply by 1:

```
df['WEEKEND'] = (df['DATE'].dt.weekday > 4) * 1
```